# There is a better way to write this sql query (union)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if there is a better way to write this sql query, in terms of performance and stability.

Because, I think I'm repeating the code many times and maybe I can do it with the CASE clause or another one.

```sql
SELECT x.Fecha,x.IdTrabajador,Cast(x.Cantidad AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Cantidad,x.Motivo,x.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
    FROM   (SELECT I.IdTrabajador,I.Fecha,
                Datediff(second, I.HoraIngreso, (SELECT HD.HoraInicio
                    FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorHorarioDetalle HD
                            INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorario H
                                    ON HD.IdTrabajadorHorario = H.IdTrabajadorHorario
                    WHERE  H.Estado = 1
                            AND HD.Estado = 1
                            AND HD.Dia = Datename(dw, I.Fecha)
                            AND H.IdTrabajador = I.IdTrabajador)) / 3600.0 AS Cantidad,
                'Sobretiempo en hora de ingreso...' AS Motivo,I.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
            FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
            WHERE  I.Estado = 1
                   AND I.IdIncidencia = 1) AS x
    WHERE  x.Cantidad > 0.00
    UNION
    SELECT x.Fecha,x.IdTrabajador,Cast(x.Cantidad AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Cantidad,x.Motivo,x.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
    FROM   (SELECT I.IdTrabajador,I.Fecha,
                Datediff(second, (SELECT HD.HoraInicioRefrigerio
                    FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorHorarioDetalle HD
                            INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorario H
                                    ON HD.IdTrabajadorHorario = H.IdTrabajadorHorario
                    WHERE  H.Estado = 1
                            AND HD.Estado = 1
                            AND HD.Dia = Datename(dw, I.Fecha)
                            AND H.IdTrabajador = I.IdTrabajador), I.HoraInicioRefrigerio) / 3600.0 AS Cantidad,
                'Sobretiempo en hora de inicio de refrigerio...' AS Motivo,I.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
            FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
            WHERE  I.Estado = 1
                   AND I.IdIncidencia = 1) AS x
    WHERE  x.Cantidad > 0.00
    UNION
    SELECT x.Fecha,x.IdTrabajador,Cast(x.Cantidad AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Cantidad,x.Motivo,x.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
    FROM   (SELECT I.IdTrabajador,I.Fecha,
                Datediff(second, I.HoraFinRefrigerio, (SELECT HD.HoraFinRefrigerio
                    FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorHorarioDetalle HD
                        INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorario H
                                ON HD.IdTrabajadorHorario = H.IdTrabajadorHorario
                    WHERE  H.Estado = 1
                        AND HD.Estado = 1
                        AND HD.Dia = Datename(dw, I.Fecha)
                        AND H.IdTrabajador = I.IdTrabajador)) / 3600.0 AS Cantidad,
                'Sobretiempo en hora de término de refrigerio...' AS Motivo,I.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
            FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
            WHERE  I.Estado = 1
                   AND I.IdIncidencia = 1) AS x
    WHERE  x.Cantidad > 0.00
    UNION
    SELECT x.Fecha,x.IdTrabajador,Cast(x.Cantidad AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Cantidad,x.Motivo,x.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
    FROM   (SELECT I.IdTrabajador,I.Fecha,
                Datediff(second, (SELECT HD.HoraFin
                    FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorHorarioDetalle HD
                            INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorario H
                                    ON HD.IdTrabajadorHorario = H.IdTrabajadorHorario
                    WHERE  H.Estado = 1
                            AND HD.Estado = 1
                            AND HD.Dia = Datename(dw, I.Fecha)
                            AND H.IdTrabajador = I.IdTrabajador), I.HoraSalida) / 3600.0 AS Cantidad,
                'Sobretiempo en hora de salida...' AS Motivo,I.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
            FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
            WHERE  I.Estado = 1
                   AND I.IdIncidencia = 1) AS x
    WHERE  x.Cantidad > 0.00
    UNION
    --Search Horas Extras (HE25 y HE35) in table TrabajadorIncidencia
    SELECT x.Fecha,x.IdTrabajador,Cast(x.Cantidad AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Cantidad,x.Motivo,x.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
    FROM   (SELECT I.IdTrabajador,I.Fecha,Datediff(second, I.HoraIngreso, I.HoraSalida) / 3600.0 AS Cantidad,'Sobretiempo en hora extra registrada...' AS Motivo,I.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
            FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
            WHERE  I.Estado = 1
                   AND ( I.IdIncidencia = 2
                          OR I.IdIncidencia = 4 )) AS x
    WHERE  x.Cantidad > 0.00
    ORDER  BY x.Fecha;
```

The previous sql query works fine, but maybe it could be better.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for indent.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is a good place to get optimization / refactoring advice on something this large. Performance questions should always include the actual execution plan too :)

Comment: I did not know that SE site. :O Thanks

Comment: what's the difference in each `UNION` ? I'm looking, but it's a lot of code and it's not jumping out (aside from the last union)

Comment: @scsimon Basically, in the order of the parameters in  ````Datediff```` (in the first four  selects)

Comment: Ah ok i see.... yeah i'm sure it could be refactored but sample data and expected output would *really* help

Comment: You need to check the execution plan to be sure.  I suspect that if you pre-read the repetitive parts into a temp table or table variable initially you will reduce the overall number of reads and the number of calls to DateDiff.  You would probably want to move WHERE criteria into the join criteria when possible.

Comment: @RaulMiranda please check out my updated answer.  I believe it should perform well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to break the problem down.  In the example below I broke the problem down into its various parts.  I think the end result is much easier to follow.

Don't think that the CTEs will create any additional processing.  I am often amazed how the efficiently SQL Server's query planner uses them.

A few caveats:
There is a chance the results might be different because the SELECTs in the DATEDIFF function were removed and replaced with a JOIN.  I'm going to assume you had a one to one relationship with the given predicates or you would've been getting errors.  Also I probably made a mistake in the cutting and pasting, so don't be surprised if this doesn't run.

```sql
WITH TrabajadorIncidenciaDetalleCte AS (
    SELECT I.*, HD.HoraInicio, HD.HoraFinRefrigerio, HD.HoraFin
    FROM [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
    INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorarioDetalle HD ON HD.Dia = DATENAME(dw, I.Fecha)
    INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorario H ON HD.IdTrabajadorHorario = H.IdTrabajadorHorario AND H.IdTrabajador = I.IdTrabajador
    WHERE  H.Estado = 1 AND HD.Estado = 1 AND I.Estado = 1 AND I.IdIncidencia = 1
)
, IncidenciaCte AS (
    SELECT IdTrabajador,Fecha, DATEDIFF(second, HoraIngreso, HoraInicio) AS Cantidad,
        'Sobretiempo en hora de ingreso...' AS Motivo, IdTrabajadorIncidencia
    FROM TrabajadorIncidenciaDetalleCte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT IdTrabajador,Fecha, DATEDIFF(second, HoraInicioRefrigerio, HoraFinRefrigerio) AS Cantidad,
        'Sobretiempo en hora de término de refrigerio...' AS Motivo, IdTrabajadorIncidencia
    FROM TrabajadorIncidenciaDetalleCte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT IdTrabajador,Fecha, DATEDIFF(second, HoraFin, HoraSalida) AS Cantidad,
        'Sobretiempo en hora de salida...' AS Motivo, IdTrabajadorIncidencia
    FROM TrabajadorIncidenciaDetalleCte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT IdTrabajador, Fecha, DATEDIFF(second, HoraIngreso, HoraSalida) AS Cantidad,
        'Sobretiempo en hora extra registrada...' AS Motivo, IdTrabajadorIncidencia
    FROM [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia
    WHERE Estado = 1 AND ( IdIncidencia = 2 OR IdIncidencia = 4 )   
)
SELECT x.Fecha, x.IdTrabajador, 
    CAST((x.Cantidad / 3600.0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Cantidad,
    x.Motivo, x.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
FROM IncidenciaCte x
WHERE x.Cantidad > 0.00
ORDER BY x.Fecha;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine!

Comment: Ps: Can I edit your query? Miss this part: ````SELECT... DATEDIFF(... HoraInicioRefrigerio...````

Comment: I went ahead and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE  x.Cantidad > 0.00` means that you eliminate any results where the subquery didn't match any rows and returns `NULL`.

Your current query will fail with an error if the subquery returns more than one row. If you are happy to go without the error in that eventuality then you can use an `INNER JOIN` instead of 4 similar subqueries, and then `CROSS APPLY ... VALUES` to unpivot the four joined column values into rows. Then `UNION` that onto the final branch.

```
SELECT I.Fecha,
       I.IdTrabajador,
       CAST(x.Cantidad / 3600.0 AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Cantidad,
       x.Motivo,
       I.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
       INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorario H
               ON H.IdTrabajador = I.IdTrabajador
                  AND H.Estado = I.Estado
       INNER JOIN [rrhh].TrabajadorHorarioDetalle HD
               ON HD.IdTrabajadorHorario = H.IdTrabajadorHorario
                  AND HD.Estado = H.Estado
       CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (DATEDIFF(second, I.HoraIngreso, HD.HoraInicio), 'Sobretiempo en hora de ingreso...'),
                            (DATEDIFF(second, HD.HoraFinRefrigerio, I.HoraInicioRefrigerio), 'Sobretiempo en hora de inicio de refrigerio...'),
                            (DATEDIFF(second, I.HoraFinRefrigerio, HD.HoraFinRefrigerio), 'Sobretiempo en hora de término de refrigerio...'),
                            (DATEDIFF(second, HD.HoraFin, I.HoraSalida), 'Sobretiempo en hora de salida...') ) x(Cantidad, Motivo)
WHERE  x.Cantidad > 0
       AND I.Estado = 1
       AND I.IdIncidencia = 1
       AND HD.Dia = DATENAME(dw, I.Fecha)
UNION
--Search Horas Extras (HE25 y HE35) in table TrabajadorIncidencia
SELECT x.Fecha,
       x.IdTrabajador,
       CAST(x.Cantidad AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS Cantidad,
       x.Motivo,
       x.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
FROM   (SELECT I.IdTrabajador,
               I.Fecha,
               DATEDIFF(second, I.HoraIngreso, I.HoraSalida) / 3600.0 AS Cantidad,
               'Sobretiempo en hora extra registrada...'              AS Motivo,
               I.IdTrabajadorIncidencia
        FROM   [rrhh].TrabajadorIncidencia I
        WHERE  I.Estado = 1
               AND ( I.IdIncidencia = 2
                      OR I.IdIncidencia = 4 )) AS x
WHERE  x.Cantidad > 0.00
ORDER  BY Fecha;
```

Comment: OMG! So close!! The previous query return 16 rows. This, 14.